# Parametric surface in 3D

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh-generation, gmsh

I want to create a mesh for a 3D surface with coordinates defined by a parametric function. Is it possible to define this mesh using Gmsh? If it is not possible, what free software do you recommend me?

Comment: I have edited your question to be more aligned to the purpose of this site. If that's not what you want, please edit it.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an option to do this through [Gmsh API](http://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html), but I am not aware of it. In the graphic interface there is not an option for this. If you are interested of doing this just in Gmsh, you should probably ask in one of the Gmsh sites.

Keep in mind that you could create the coordinates of your mesh using a map from a rectangular grid (in parametric coordinates) to $\mathbb{R}^3$. For example, you could compute the coordinates using Python and then export the mesh using [Meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio). The original map can be a regular rectangle.

If you want a software with a graphic user interface for this, I would suggest to check [MathMod](https://github.com/parisolab/mathmod).